# openvpn TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

Tags: configuration, openvpn, port-forwarding

TLS Error: TLS handshake failed

What ports need to be open for OpenVPN to work?

Server configuration:

```
 server

 port 1194

 proto udp

 server-bridge 192.168.1.104 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.160 192.168.1.170

 dev tap0

 ca ca.crt

 cert server.crt

 tun-mtu 1454

 key server.key

 dh dh1024.pem

 up "/etc/openvpn/up.sh br0"

 down "/etc/openvpn/down.sh br0"

 ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

 keepalive 10 600

 comp-lzo

 persist-key

 persist-tun

 verb 3

 mute 20

 status openvpn-status.log

 client-config-dir ccd

 client-to-client
```

Client configuration:

```
client:

dev tap

remote servername.com 1194

nobind

resolv-retry infinite

persist-key

persist-tun

ca ca.crt

cert client.crt

key client.key

tls-auth ta.key 1

cipher BF-CBC

comp-lzo

verb 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The port that is needed to be open is 1194 UDP in your current config. Also you need to make sure the client cipher matches the server cipher.